# PDO - getting total results when LIMIT is used, with parameter binding

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm running a fairly complex MySQL query (multiple `LEFT JOIN`, `GROUP_CONCAT` and bound parameters) with PDO. Due to the complexity of the query I have added a `LIMIT` clause to the end to return a particular set of the data - which is shown in a paginated table in my application.

The pagination requires the total number of results to be found. I didn't realise this was so awkward but have read the following:

- [get total for limit in mysql using same query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279390/get-total-for-limit-in-mysql-using-same-query)
- [Get total number of rows when using LIMIT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887266/get-total-number-of-rows-when-using-limit)
- [How to count all rows when using SELECT with LIMIT in MySQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439829/how-to-count-all-rows-when-using-select-with-limit-in-mysql-query)

The performance of `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` was terrible so I can't use this.

The only way I could think to write this was to run a second query, using `COUNT`. But because the query uses parameter binding (for search terms the user has entered), I have to bind them again in the second query.

My initial query to get the results looks like this:

```
// Get the results
$sql = ' '; // Complex query
$limit = ' LIMIT ' . $start . ', ' . $offset;
$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);

// Search parameters
if (isset($search['term1'])) {
    $stmt->bindValue('term1', '%' . $search['term1'] . '%');
} 
if (isset($search['term2'])) {
    $stmt->bindValue('term2', '%' . $search['term2'] . '%');
}
if (isset($search['term3'])) {
    $stmt->bindValue('term3', '%' . $search['term3'] . '%');
}

$stmt->execute();
return $stmt->fetchAll('assoc');
```

Now I need to remove the `LIMIT` so I've done the following:

```
$stmt_count = $connection->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (' . $sql . ') AS total_results');
$stmt_count->execute();
```

But this doesn't work, because I'll need to bind the parameters again. Surely there's a more efficient way, than repeating all of the binding on to `$stmt_count`??

```
 if (isset($search['term1'])) {
    $stmt_count->bindValue('term1', '%' . $search['term1'] . '%');
} 
if (isset($search['term2'])) {
    $stmt_count->bindValue('term2', '%' . $search['term2'] . '%');
}
if (isset($search['term3'])) {
    $stmt_count->bindValue('term3', '%' . $search['term3'] . '%');
}
```

Incidentally, I cannot believe how something as basic as this has been made so difficult! It's a very basic requirement to be able to easily know the total number of results of a query.

Comment: Create an array with the parameters and pass it to your `$stmt->execute($params)` instead. Then you can reuse the array for the next call. http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: How can I build that array up? If I do things such as `$bind[] = ['term1' => '%' . $search['term1'] . '%']; $bind[] = ['term2' => '%' . $search['term2'] . '%']` it doesn't work. Presumably because although `execute($bind)` accepts an array, the contents have to be formatted more like a string?

Comment: You're currently building a multidimensional array, which is wrong. Just do: `$bind = []; $bind[':term1'] = '%' . $search['term1'] . '%'; $bind[':term2'] = ....`